# plugin-list-category-post Instructions

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

A basic question from a very humble and intimidated newbie.

The List-Category-Post plugin looks like it will let me do exactly what I want to do, which is what the Wordpress codex calls "A page of posts." I downloaded the plugin instead of changing any templates myself. As per instructions, I went to the admin menu and activated it. I even found the widget under the appearance menu. I know absolutely nothing about coding, so I want to avoid editing files on templates and instead "use the default [file] included in the plugin's code." How do I connect this to a page so that I can actually see the categorized posts appearing? I feel like there must be something very simple that I'm missing--a box to check or some custom menu to activate.

I hope this is not too basic a question for this forum. I came here because the plugin download page said that Fernando had chosen this forum for support. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Its a great plugin and i believe the developer is a member here. To use it simply create a new page and use the plugin's shortcode `[catlist id=1]` 
change 1 with the actual category id.

to read more about its features and ways you can use it : 
http://foro.picandocodigo.net/discussion/251/list-category-posts-documentation/

and to use the plugins advanced Template system:
http://foro.picandocodigo.net/discussion/253/list-category-posts-using-templates/